# 'Permission denied' trying mkdir in 'Documents' folder using Linux on Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, cygwin, mkdir

I'm running Windows 10 and have tried creating a folder under 'Documents' folder using Cygwin, Git Bash, and Ubuntu subsystem for Windows 10 to no avail.

```
mkdir testfolder
```

Have also tried

```
sudo mkdir testfolder
```

and I get the resulting message `mkdir: cannot create directory 'testfolder': Permission denied`

I've tried running as administrator, I've tried doing `chmod 777 Documents`, I am root when using Ubuntu, but nothing seems to solve this error message.

One other note, I have no problem creating a directory in other folders at the same level such as 'Downloads' or 'Desktop'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: compare the permissions you see with `icacls` and `getfacl` of the directories.

Comment: I'm new to this, but I ran `getfacl` on 'Documents' and got this:
`$ getfacl Documents/
# file: Documents/
# owner: iantf
# group: 197609 <unknown>
user::rwx
group::r-x
other:r-x`
I am running as iantf and confirmed using `whoami`

Comment: On my W7 the owner of `Documents` and `Downloads` is `Administrators` and there is a line like `user:iantf:rwx` on both. The `group: 197609 <unknown>` means that some forgotten user has created the dir.

Comment: Hmm now when I run `getfacl` I get iantf:rwx on both:
`$ getfacl Documents/
# file: Documents/
# owner: iantf
# group: iantf
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:SYSTEM:rwx
group:Administrators:rwx
mask:rwx
other:---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:SYSTEM:rwx
default:group:Administrators:rwx
default:group:iantf:rwx
default:mask:rwx
default:other:---`